# Use Power BI Desktop to display data from Event Hubs

Tags: azure, powerbi-desktop, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I need to display data from Event Hubs on Power BI **Desktop**.

The link below is using Azure Power BI and Stream Analytics.

But I need to use Power BI Desktop and can use Stream Analytics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-tutorial-visualize-anomalies

Any idea?

Comment: Hey, do you need to build a pipeline, or is just a one time thing? If it's a one time thing, for purely local processing you can use the Azure Stream Analytics Tools extension in Visual Studio Code to dump the traffic in json files, and then consume those files from Power BI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/visual-studio-code-local-run-live-input

Comment: If you can use the Power BI live service, you should give a try to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-streaming

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will have a look at the two links you provided. I am not sure what do you mean by a `pipeline`? But it is not a one-time thing. It would be great if you could clarify it. Thx again.

Comment: By pipeline I meant a recurring job, sorry for the confusion. Do you need the processing to happens continuously, in real time, or does your dashboard only needs to be updated every hour, day... Do you intend to host that dashboard on the Power BI service, or will you only ever consume the report in Power BI desktop?